# How can i scroll only posts? (TextField)

Tags: flutter, scroll, containers, textfield

I want the blue lines not to disappear when it scrolls up.
The blue lines are related to OutlineInputBorder. But it stays inside of SingleChildScrollView widget. How can I do it?

[image]

**related codes**

```
Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _textEditingController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                maxLines: null,
                                autocorrect: true,
                                enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                                enableSuggestions: true,
                                textCapitalization:
                                    TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Bir not ekleyin",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting container inside container. But I removed the OutlineInputBorder.

If you have a better solution, please let me know.

**new codes**

```
                       Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18.0))),
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: _textEditingController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                  autocorrect: true,
                                  enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                                  enableSuggestions: true,
                                  textCapitalization:
                                      TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Bir not ekleyin",
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    // border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    //   borderRadius:
                                    //       BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                    // ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```